# 【追記】スタック・オーバーフローの交流会

Tags: 討議, 交流会

この夏に交流会を開催しようと思っています。

1. 6月29日（木）東京
2. 7月下旬（未定）大阪と東京

交流会・ユーザー会のイベントについては[このグループ](http://peatix.com/group/54966/view)で共有します。

### [6月29日（木）東京](http://peatix.com/event/276720/view)

*更新：場所が決まりました。イベントページをご覧ください*

別件で東京を訪問予定です。その際、バーで飲物と軽食を準備しますので、弊職とコミュニティメンバーが自由に交流できる場を持ちたいと思います。Tシャツで参加予定ですので、仕事後のビールなど気軽な参加も大歓迎です。

ビリヤードをやりながらビールとプログラミングについて話しましょうか？

### 7月下旬にスペシャルゲストが来日します

当社の開発者[konamiman](https://stackoverflow.com/users/story/4574)が来日します。その間、東京と大阪で交流会を開催する予定です。彼の自己紹介はこちらです：

> 1985年のクリスマス、11歳の頃に初のパソコンを手に入れました。[MSX](https://ja.wikipedia.org/wiki/MSX)の[Canon
>
> V-20](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Canon_V-20)でした。はじめはゲーム利用のみでしたが、数年後にBASICでのプログラミングからassemblyに興味をもちました。
>
> 最終的にメーカーもユーザーもMSXパソコン（PC・Mac以外のパソコン）のサポート・利用を終了しましたが、一部のユーザーが使い続けてるため新しいハードウェアとソフトウェアを今でも作っています。konamimanもそのユーザーの仲間になって、[assemblyのみで作られたTCP/IPスタック](http://konamiman.com/msx/msx-s.html#inl)、[NextorOS](http://konamiman.com/msx/msx-s.html#nextor)等のMSXソフトを作成しました。
>
> 1997年にインターネット経由に日本人の女性と偶然出会いました。konamimanの妹が日本語の練習相手をさがして彼女と出会い、その6年後、konamimanはその彼女と結婚しました。現在スペインに住んでいますが、年に一度は日本に帰国しています。
>
> 2002年よりプロの開発者として勤めています。[Stack Overflow en
>
> Español](https://es.stackoverflow.com)のベータ中モデレーターとして活躍した後、2016年からStack
> OverflowのCore Developerになりました。毎日はスペインからリモートで働いています。
>
> 関連情報（英語・スペイン語）：
>
> - [MSXサイト](http://www.konamiman.com)
> - [GitHub repositories](https://github.com/konamiman)
> - [Konamiman's talk about his TCP/IP stack](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=SJomQNEgbww)

### 7月20日（木）大阪（[難波・梅田のどっちか](https://strawpoll.com/y6cfar8)）

### 7月27日（木）東京（[東京・新宿・渋谷のいずれか](https://strawpoll.com/d7dfd79)）

---

質問等があれば、是非ご教示ください。お待ちしております！