# スタック・オーバーフローの交流会に参加するには？　また、交流会を開くには？

Tags: サポート, よくある質問の案, 交流会

スタック・オーバーフローのコミュニティ交流会が開かれたことがあるそうです。

- 交流会に参加するには、どうすれば良いですか？
- 交流会を開くには、どうすれば良いですか？

[←FAQ目次に戻る](/q/1484)

Answer (score 6, accepted):

### 交流会に参加したい

スタック・オーバーフローの交流会は、[メタ](https://ja.meta.stackoverflow.com/)でアナウンスされます。時々メタを確認してみてください。[交流会](/questions/tagged/%e4%ba%a4%e6%b5%81%e4%bc%9a) というタグがつくはずなので、この[タグをウォッチ](https://ja.stackoverflow.com/help/interesting-topics)しておくと便利かもしれません。またメインサイトのサイドバーに表示されることもあるので、時々見てみてください。

参加するための手段はそのメタ投稿に書かれているはずです。これにしたがってください。ご参加お待ちしております！ :-)

### 交流会を開きたい

交流会を開きたいですか？　ぜひそのことをメタへ投稿してください！　「2038年1月に東京で交流会を開きたい」みたいなタイトルでご投稿頂ければ、そこから議論が始まるでしょう。

参加賞用にスタック・オーバーフロー T シャツが欲しいなど、Stack Exchange 社からの支援が欲しければ、チャット等でモデレーターに ping してください。モデレーターが Stack Exchange 社員に掛け合ってくれることでしょう。

日程が決まり、人が集まれば、交流会の開催です！　楽しみましょう！　その場で集合写真を撮るなどして感想をコミュニティに教えて頂ければ幸いです。

交流会を開いて、コミュニティの仲を深めたり、スタック・オーバーフローについて理解を深めたりしましょう！

スタック・オーバーフロー交流会諸々について語ることができるチャットルームは[こちらです :-)](https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/95328/soja)！

### 交流会を開く際に考える細かいこと一覧

もしあなたが細かいことを気にする人なら、ここから下に書くことが役に立つかもしれません。ぶっちゃけ細かすぎることばかりなので、気にしなくても大丈夫だと思います。

**長いので、ここを読む前にまずは交流会を開いちゃいましょう。**

#### 交流会を開くまで

- 日時と開催都市をまず決めることになります。

  - 関東開催か、関西開催か、名古屋開催か、はたまたそれ以外の都市か……。人口分布的に人が集まりやすいのは東京でしょうが、そこでばかりやっていると偏ってしまいます。人が集まりそうであれば、大阪や名古屋など他都市での開催も考慮してみてください。
  - 集まるのは IT エンジニアが多いでしょうから、2038 年 1 月 19 日など、IT エンジニアが集まりにくい日付は避けるべきです。交流会をリードする方たちが来れる日の中から、一番人が集まりやすい日時を選びましょう。メタでアンケートをとる方法もあります。
  - ちなみに Stack Exchange 社的にはもともと四半期ごとに 1 回交流会を開くくらいの想定と聞きました [要出典]。
- 交流会の形式を決めます。わいわい飲み会でしょうか。ピザパーティー？　ライトニングトーク (LT) 付きの交流会？　勉強会っぽい発表＋懇親会？　何人か登壇者を選んでパネルディスカッション？　ポスター発表？　もくもく作業会？　ハッカソン？

  - **交流会の目的**から先に決めると決めやすいかもしれません。

    - 実例：[2017 年、東京での交流会](https://ja.meta.stackoverflow.com/q/2511/19110)は、プログラミングについて話すため、Stack Exchange の開発者も交えてビリヤードバーで交流しました。
    - 実例：[交流会 in 東京 2019](https://ja.meta.stackoverflow.com/q/2982/19110)では、コミュニティの仲を深めたかったのでビアバッシュっぽい形式にしました。会話のタネにするため、LT も募集しました。
- 具体的な場所を決めます。人数によってはお店を貸し切ることができるでしょう。企業等の会議室をお借りするのも良さそうです。費用と相談なので、Stack Exchange 社員と相談しつつ決めることになります。

  - 実例：[交流会 in 東京 2019](https://ja.meta.stackoverflow.com/q/2982/19110)では、わいわい話したかったのでお店開催にすることにし、aki さんに選んで頂きました。結果バーのようなお店を貸し切りました。開催日の数日前になるまで実際どのくらい人数が集まるのか分からなかったため、少しひやひやでした。開催日の 7 日前の時点で 12 人ほど申し込んでくださっていて、前日には 14 人まで増えました。当日 2 人キャンセルが出て、結局 12 人が集まりました。[具体的な統計はこちら](https://i.stack.imgur.com/4OOtJ.png)。
  - PC を持ち込む人が多そうな場合、**Wi-Fi や電源**も気になります。
  - 発表をする場合、プロジェクターの有無やスクリーンの大きさ・位置も気になります。
- メタに投稿する。

  - まだ投稿していなければ、交流会についてメタに投稿してください。
  - [交流会](/questions/tagged/%e4%ba%a4%e6%b5%81%e4%bc%9a) をつけてください。
  - モデレーターに頼んで [注目](/questions/tagged/%e6%b3%a8%e7%9b%ae) をつけても良いでしょう。このタグをつけるとメインサイトのサイドバーに表示されるようになります。
- 参加者を募ります。メタだと管理しにくいので、外部サイトを使っています。

  - 選択肢1: [connpass](https://connpass.com/dashboard/)。[スタック・オーバーフローのグループ](https://soja.connpass.com/)があるので、ここ所属のイベントを作成してください。モデレーターに頼めば、イベント管理者やグループ管理者に設定するなどしてイベントが管理できるようにしてくれることでしょう。

    - connpass では発表資料を登録できたりするなど色々機能があるので、便利です。
  - 選択肢2: Google Form。
- 発表をする場合：

  - 発表者も募集します。

    - 一般の勉強会と異なり「スタック・オーバーフロー交流会」だと何について話せばよいのかすぐには分かりにくいので、会の目的を説明したり、サンプルの発表タイトルを載せておくと良いです。
  - 内容をインターネットで配信するか決めます。

    - 実例：[2015年のイベント](https://devdays.peatix.com/view)では、Ustream で発表をライブ配信しました。
    - 実例：[交流会 in 東京 2019](https://ja.meta.stackoverflow.com/q/2982/19110)では、LT はあくまで会話のタネで、その場の交流を大事にしたかったので配信は行いませんでした。そもそも配信機材のアテが無かったという理由もあります。代わりに発表者のみなさんに発表資料のアップロードをお願いしました。
  - あらかじめ発表タイトルだけ教えていただいておくと、参加者も予習しやすいです。
  - 発表者には、難易度設定を適切にお願いしておくと便利かもしれません。これは勉強会のスタイルによるのですが、聴衆側のレベルをあらかじめ設定して公開しておいたり、逆に発表者に適宜説明をお願いしたり、発表中のインタラクティブな質問を OK にしたり……などなどケースバイケースです。

    - 実例：[交流会 in 東京 2019](https://ja.meta.stackoverflow.com/q/2982/19110)は小規模な会だったので、聴衆の知識を仮定せず発表資料を作ってもらい、現地で質問してもらいました。またスタック・オーバーフロー初心者の方が数名いらっしゃることが事前に分かっていたので、発表前に司会からスタック・オーバーフロー自体の説明と交流会の目的の説明を手短に行いました。
  - スライドを使う場合、文字サイズをなるべく大きくしてもらうと遠くからも見やすいです。意外と声は聞き取りづらいです。
  - 会場に**マイク**があるかどうかもポイントです。
- イベントを宣伝します。せっかく交流会を企画しても、それがあることを知らしめないと参加者が集まりません。メタや SNS を使い、イベントを宣伝しましょう。バズの波を生みましょう。

  - 実例：[交流会 in 東京 2019](https://ja.meta.stackoverflow.com/q/2982/19110) の参加者の方何名かに伺ったところ、メインサイトのサイドバーに載っていたからイベントを知った方や、知人の開発者が Twitter で言及していたからイベントを知った方が何名かいらっしゃいました。

他のエンジニア向けイベントがどのように開催されてるのかも参考になります。また、オライリーの『アート・オブ・コミュニティ』のようにコミュニティ運営についてまとめられた書籍も参考になるでしょう。よくある勉強会と違いバーでわいわいするような形での開催実績もあるので、会の目的に合わせて柔軟に設定するのが良さそうです。会の規模感にあわせて問題が変わってくるので、どういう会にしたいかをイメージしながら考えると吉です。

#### 交流会中のもろもろ

- プレゼンテーションや LT をする場合、司会をひとり決めて話者紹介やタイムキープ、質問の管理をすると間延びを防げます。自由な会話の時間を確保するためにも、司会がリードしましょう。
- **名札**があると便利です。
- 発表をする場合：

  - プロジェクターの対応端子に注意してください。あらかじめ伺っておくと発表者の方それぞれが変換ケーブルを用意してくださることでしょう。
  - 急にオフラインになっても発表できるようにしておくと良いです。特に Google Slide は設定によってはオフラインだと使えなくなります。PDF としてダウンロードしておくと良いです。
  - 誰かのパソコンが使えなくなるかもしれません。PDF を USB にダウンロードしておくと他の人のパソコンでも発表できるでしょう。
  - これは本当に細かいことを気にする人向けですが、必要に応じて司会が予備物品を持っていくと安心です。延長コード、ペン、レーザーなど。
- 交流会の様子をコミュニティに知ってもらうため、写真を撮りましょう。

  - 集合写真もそうですし、参加者の方に撮ってもらって SNS に投稿してもらいましょう。
  - 顔出し NG の方に配慮しましょう。イベント開始前に写真撮影について言及し、参加者が写真を撮る場合も「撮影、アップロード等自由だが、個人情報に配慮して」とアナウンスするのが良さそうです。
  - ID と顔の対応が付くことが嫌な方は写真撮影のときだけ名札を裏返すと良いです。
  - 発表者の方にあらかじめ聞いておいて、スライド撮影可かどうかを明らかにしておくとアップロードしやすいです。
- 未成年の方に配慮しましょう。お酒やたばこです。お店によっては未成年の方を別テーブルに隔離しないといけなかったりするので、あらかじめお店の方と相談しておくと安心です。
- Dietary restriction（アレルギー、宗教・信条上の理由などで食べられないものがあること）がある方をあらかじめ聞いておくと、お店の方と相談して対応を用意しておきやすいです。
- 実況用 Twitter ハッシュタグがあると便利です。

  - 実例：[交流会 in 東京 2019](https://ja.meta.stackoverflow.com/q/2982/19110)では「#スタック・オーバーフローMeetUp」というタグを用意したのですが、正直これはスマホで打ちにくく失敗でした。「#スタック・オーバーフロー」とか「#スタックオーバーフロー」とか「#SOja」で良かったです。表記揺れが起きにくく打ちやすいタグが良さそうです。
- 一般の勉強会で知られている注意点も調べておくと良いかもしれません。

  - 当日ドタキャンする方がいます。

    - どうしようもない事情が発生することもあるので、一概に悪いとは言えません。どちらかというとしょうがなく発生し得るものなので、発生したときに備えておくと良いです。
    - お店で開催する場合、ドタキャンが発生した場合の処理についてあらかじめ相談しておきましょう。
    - connpass 等のサイトでは、よくキャンセルする人が分かったり、ブラックリストを作れたりします。活用しましょう。
  - 飲食無料の勉強会ばかり狙うフリーライダーがいます。

    - 実例：[エンジニアイベントを初主催。そして事件は起こった](https://www.wantedly.com/companies/spacemarket/post_articles/22855)
  - 過度な交流を求めてくる人がいます。第三者が是非を判断しにくいので難しいところです。

    - 人材発見を目的に名刺交換をしまくる人：会の目的によって是非が変わるので、適宜判断です。悪気が無い方もいらっしゃるので、あらかじめ会の目的を強調すると良いかもしれません。会話がもりあがって名刺交換という自然な流れもあるので判断しにくいです。
    - セクシャルハラスメントをする人：性別関係なくいます。会の様子を注視し、適宜いさめましょう。また、困ったことがあればコアメンバーに相談できるようにしておきましょう。

      - 実例：[もう勉強会には行かないと思う](https://anond.hatelabo.jp/20181012090959)
      - 実例：[「俺の最寄駅で降りよう」](https://twitter.com/llminatoll/status/1136551425696100352)
  - 攻撃的な発表・会話があるかもしれません。適宜いさめましょう。

    - 判断基準として、Code of Conduct が守れているかどうかはひとつのラインになります。
  - **嬉しいことに、この回答を最初に書いている人 (nekketsuuu) の知る限りスタック・オーバーフローの会でこのようなことは起こっていません。** 注意しすぎても失礼なので、頭の片隅においておくくらいがちょうど良いかと思います。

    - 必要なら、アンチハラスメントポリシーを制定するのもアリです。

#### 交流会が終わったら

- 集合写真をメタに投稿しましょう。
- 参加者の方に感想ブログ記事を書いてもらうのも良さそうです。
- 参加者の方に満足度アンケートをとることもできます。
- 次の交流会の予定を早めに決めておくと、次を開きやすいです。