# 正式版1周年記念Webミーティングを12/17に開催します！→しました！

Tags: 討議, 交流会

2021年12月16日よりスタック・オーバーフロー日本語版が正式版となりました。
[祝スタック・オーバーフロー公開7周年をむかえ正式版へ](https://ja.meta.stackoverflow.com/q/3653)

早いもので正式版となってから1年が経とうとしています。
そこで、1周年を記念して下記の予定で簡単なWebミーティングを開きます。
大人数のWebミーティングのため、ウェビナーのライトニングトーク(LT)をメインコンテンツとして、コメント質問などを含めて盛り上げていきたいと思います。
ぜひこの節目を皆様で一緒にお祝いしまし<strike>ょう</strike>た！

@NicolasChabanovsky さんが**お祝いメッセージをお寄せくださいました！**
[スタック・オーバーフローの正式版一周年記念をお祝いしましょう！](https://ja.meta.stackoverflow.com/q/3827/9820)

1. **日時**：2022年12月17日(土) 21時(JST) **Start time**: 2022-12-17T21:00:00+09:00
2. **場所**：Zoom ウェビナー(URLは https://zoom.us/j/92080226681 です)
3. **構成**：1時間を目安としたLT大会。下記は現時点での発表順と申込時のLTの方向性(※実際の内容とは異なります)

   - オープニング：このイベント解説とスタックオーバーフローの歴史概略
   - **Nicolas Chabanovsky**さん：Short intro
     [動画.movダウンロード](https://payaneco.github.io/soja-meetup-2022/soja_meetup_2022_nicolas.mov)
   - **nekketsuuu**さん：[Upvote, More!](https://nekketsuuu.github.io/assets/slides/2022-12-17-upvote-more.pdf)
   - **TK**さん：[スタック・オーバーフローにコントリビュートしはじめて良かったこと](https://zenn.dev/takuyakikuchi/articles/db8239b8fabe31)
   - **philippe**さん：[スタック・オーバーフロー公開一周年祝辞](https://docs.google.com/presentation/d/e/2PACX-1vRKrJbnew33LjYg1jA60kJUG2vjvTLyabFNnhmMq11FjNL6gtku8LIv2ofU-1x9deCX8VI2dNvi9jkc/pub?start=false&loop=false&delayms=3000&slide=id.g77889fe819_0_0)
     [動画.movダウンロード](https://payaneco.github.io/soja-meetup-2022/soja_meetup_2022_philippe.mov)
   - **payaneco**：[スタック・オーバーフローアンケート結果から見るスタック・オーバーフロー](https://payaneco.github.io/soja-meetup-2022/soja-meetup-2022.pdf)
   - エンディング
4. **人数上限**：500名(コアメンバー、発表者を含む)

一般参加枠を[connpass](https://soja.connpass.com/event/266740/)に追加いたしました。
一般参加枠に登録していない方も視聴できる運営を想定していますが、登録しておくとconnpassのリマインダを受けられるなど便利な機能が使えますので、ぜひ興味のある方はご登録ください。

※もしも万が一、一般参加者が定員数に近くなった場合は、Web会議のURLをLT参加者と一般参加者のみに展開することになります。

企画について適宜決定次第この質問を更新してまいります。
質問やご意見は随時コメントなどでお寄せください。

もちろんLTも一般参加も参加は無料です！
お気軽なご参加をお待ちしておりますので、何卒よろしくお願いいたします。

追記1: 諸事情により人数制限を100名までとさせていただきました。
追記2: Zoom MeetingからZoom Webinarに変更し、人数制限を500名に増員しました。

追記3: 二次配信の可否につきましては、 @payaneco またはSOスタッフへの連絡なく配信することはご遠慮願います。
あまり堅苦しくはしたくないのですが、主催者の意図から外れた編集や切り抜きなどによりLT参加者などに不利益が発生することを防ぐためです。何卒ご理解ください。
後日見逃し配信の予定は今のところございませんが、ご要望があれば考慮いたします。
なお、当日のウェビナー視聴者にコメントなどを求めることはございますが「LTの質疑応答のために(自発的な)ご意見があればお寄せください」という程度の強制力を持たない要求です。
特定の人物に名指しで発言を依頼することや視聴者の発言を強要することはございませんので、動画のリアルタイム配信を閲覧する程度の気楽さでご参加いただきたく存じます。

追記4:ご参加くださいました皆様へ。司会進行のつたない点が多々ございましたが、ご参加くださいました皆様のおかげで無事に終了いたしました。取り急ぎ御礼申し上げます。本当にありがとうございました！

---

なお個人の宣伝ではございますが、ミーティングに先立ってpayaneco謹製のSOjaアンケートを公開いたしました。
https://payaneco-so-survey-kakkokari-index-5ql7t3.streamlit.app/

アンケートにご回答いただいた内容は匿名化した上で私のLTにて統計作成および意見のご紹介をさせていただきます。
アンケートの実施はスタック・オーバーフローとは直接関係がありませんが、今後の運営の参考としてスタッフに展開する予定です。
ぜひぜひ！こちらも皆様のご協力をお願いいたします。

Comment: +1: たのしみです。LT 枠以外の参加者枠は connpass では募集されませんか？　自由参加ですかね。

Comment: 今のところ自由参加を考えています。参加者が300人を超える場合は先着順になりますが、超えなそうな気がするので。ただし、もし一般参加者にステッカーなど配れるならもくもく会のように一般参加者募集欄を作るかもしれません。

Comment: connpass に登録しておくと開催間際に connpass から通知が届いたりするので便利かな〜と思った次第でした。ありがとうございます！

Comment: なるほど、リマインダは良いですね。一般参加枠を追加しました！

Comment: 本文を書き換え、場所と人数を記載しました。「参加者が300人」というコメントは誤りとなりましたので、申し訳ありませんがご注意をお願いいたします。

Comment: LTはともかく、一般枠で(チャットであれ)コメントなどを求められても困るから参加できないという人だっていると思うので、気軽に配信とかすればいいのでは？

Comment: @dameo 今回は既に予算が付き、準備を進めておりますので予定通りZoom Wibinar形式で進めてまいります。いただきましたご意見は今後の参考にさせていただきます。

Comment: どこまでがコミュニティでどこからが会社なのかよく分かりませんが、配信不可能ということなのでしょうか？不可能ならどなたか配信してくれる人とかいるのでしょうか？
また第三者が(勝手に)配信していいのか？など決めておいた方がいいのかもですね。

Comment: 構成に具体的な発表順を追加しました。LTのタイトルや方向性はイベント申込時の内容をそのまま転記しました。変更したい場合は直接編集またはコメントまたは[何でも部屋](https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/17893/soja-chatroom)チャットをお願いします。

Comment: 本日、はじめてスタッフ以外の方から日本語で[アンケート](https://payaneco-so-survey-kakkokari-index-5ql7t3.streamlit.app/)へのご回答をいただきました。ありがとうございます！

Comment: ZoomウェビナーのミーティングURLを記載しました。過去ログでは当日**夜**にURLを追加すると言ってましたが撤回します。

Comment: ウェビナー入場できるようにしました。
定刻通り21時から開始予定です。よろしくお願いします！

Comment: 会社との境界が不明な点、身内意識が強く個人も顔が見えない点、それなのに気軽に見れる配信手段すら提供しないのが問題なのだと思いますよ。今回は見てないけど、個人的にはどんどんオープンにしていった方がよいかと思います。

Comment: 発表資料のURLを追記しました。

Answer (score 6, accepted):

プレゼント  についてのご案内です

**[Payanecoさんの SOja アンケート](https://payaneco-so-survey-kakkokari-index-5ql7t3.streamlit.app/)に答えられた方**
および
**Zoom Webinar に参加**のみなさま
 希望者全員にスタック・オーバーフロー（カタカナ）ステッカー

**[Connpass に参加者として登録](https://soja.connpass.com/event/266740/)された方**
 Stack Overflow のオリジナル靴下

**LT 発表者 のみなさま**
 Stack Overflow 特製Tシャツ（プラスもう一つなにかご希望のアイテム）

[image: Stack]

後日スタック・オーバーフローから送付先をうかがうメールを登録時のメールアドレスへお送りさせていただきますのでよろしくお願いいたします。

Comment: 豪華プレゼントの写真ありがとうございます

Answer (score 1):

## オンライン交流会を開くには

今回のイベントの準備手順や[Zoom Webinars](https://explore.zoom.us/ja/products/webinars/)の設定をメモしておきます。
今後スタック・オーバーフローでオンラインイベントを開きたい方の参考になれば幸いです。

なお、交流会を開く際の心構えなどは[スタック・オーバーフローの交流会に参加するには？　また、交流会を開くには？](https://ja.meta.stackoverflow.com/q/3017/9820)をご参照ください。

### 事前準備

- メタ質問を立ててコアメンバー募集および情報収集
  [ベータ卒業記念イベントを企画しよう【LT会場のご意見募集中】](https://ja.meta.stackoverflow.com/q/3683/9820)
- このメタ質問でWebミーティングの方針や日程を表明
- connpassで参加者を募集
  [スタック・オーバーフロー正式版1周年記念 MeetUp](https://connpass.com/event/266740/)
- connpassのアンケート機能を使って下記を確認

  - connpass登録名とスタック・オーバーフロー登録名が異なる場合、SOjaの登録名を教えてください。
  - LT後に質疑応答の時間を設けて良いですか？
  - 現時点で考えているLTのタイトルや方向性を教えてください。
- 1ヶ月契約でZoom Webinarsに登録
  ※Zoom Oneプランなど、他の有料プランとは異なるので注意
- 発表順を決めてメタ質問とconnpassで告知
- connpassのメッセージ機能で発表者に対してZoom Webinars登録名とメールアドレスを質問
  パネリスト権限を付けるため、ウェビナーにメールアドレスを登録して招待URLを生成
- Zoom Webinarsでイベントのスケジュールを登録し、メタ質問とconnpassでURLを告知
  スケジュールの設定は下記

  - 登録の『必須』チェックなし
  - 認証の『パネリストに参加時に認証を行うことを求める』チェックなし
  - 認証の『出席者に参加時に認証を行うことを求める』チェックなし
  - オプションの『Q&A』『練習セッションを有効にする』にチェックを入れる
  - オプションの『ウェビナーを自動的にレコーディングします』にチェックを入れなかったことを後で後悔する
- connpassのメッセージ機能で発表者に対して練習セッションの時間を告知

  - 20:00-20:30を練習セッションの時間とした

### イベント当日作業

- 20:00に練習セッションを開始して、Zoom Webinarsの設定を変更

  - 『質問と回答』で『匿名での質問を許可する』をチェック
  - 『質問と回答』で『回答済みの質問のみ』をチェック
  - 『ウェビナー チャット』のハンバーガーメニューから『チャット可能対象（パネリスト）』で『全員』をチェック
  - 『ウェビナー チャット』のハンバーガーメニューから『出席者チャット可能対象』で『全員』をチェック
  - 『ウェビナー チャット』の『宛先』で『全員』をチェック
- 練習セッションで発表者のログイン順に対応

  - 発表者のマイクやスライド表示が正常なことを確認
  - 司会進行について簡単に発表者へ説明
- 20:40ごろに練習セッションを終了し、ウェビナーを開始

  - ウェビナー開始後は、画面共有で一般参加者向けの注意事項などを表示
- 21:00イベント開始

『質問と回答』の設定
[image: 『質問と回答』の設定]

『ウェビナー チャット』の設定
[image: 『ウェビナー チャット』の設定]