# 結果発表：2023年 春のプラス投票キャンペーン  

Tags: 討議, 投票, キャンペーン

2022年12月に開催された[正式版一周年記念 LT イベント](https://ja.meta.stackoverflow.com/q/3813/14055)で「プラス投票を盛り上げたい」という[お声](https://nekketsuuu.github.io/assets/slides/2022-12-17-upvote-more.pdf)をいただき、このたび、**春のプラス投票キャンペーン   を企画しました！**

今回の賞品はスタック・オーバーフロー ウォーターボトルです。

[image: 3 nice water bottles which may bring you some positivity]

以下、各部門の Winner 合計 3 名にお送りします。

1. 期間中に最も多くの**プラス投票**を行ったユーザー
2. 期間中に最も多くの投票を得た**質問**の投稿者
3. 期間中に最も多くの投票を得た**回答**の投稿者

投稿期間：
2023年4月1日(土)〜4月21日(金)

投票期間：
2023年4月1日(土)〜5月5日(金)

結果発表は5月8日(月)に Meta サイトにて行います。
（結果発表までの 2 週間は投票を得る機会を増やすためのものです。）

### [キャンペーン内容]

#### - 対象

スタック・オーバーフロー ユーザー
(信用度が低い人も高い人も中くらいの人も、全員)

#### - 期間とエントリー方法

4月1日(土)から5月5日(金)までに、スタック・オーバーフロー [メインサイト](https://ja.stackoverflow.com/) に投票 / 投稿（質問 / 回答）してください。こちらで集計するので特別なエントリーは不要です。

- Meta サイトでの回答はノーカウントとします。
- 時間はスタック・オーバーフロー上の表示に従います。つまり、UTCです。

#### - 賞品

ウォーターボトル
もしかすると他にも何か嬉しいものがもらえるかもしれません（^人^）

#### - 発表

5月8日(月) [Meta サイト](https://ja.meta.stackoverflow.com/)にて
Winner の方々へは発表後に送付先を確認するためのメールが送られます。

**どんどんプラス票を投じて、気持ちもプラスに素敵な春をお過ごしください〜！**

Comment: @nekketsuuu さん、大変お忙しい中 SEDE でのご確認をありがとうございました！

Answer (score 5):

**結果発表**

1. 期間中に最も多くのプラス投票を行ったユーザー
   **payaneco さん**
   [image: payaneco]
2. 期間中に最も多くのプラス投票を得た質問の投稿者
   **Bladean Mericle さん**
   [image: Bladean Mericle]
   [配列を使わずにCS8603を回避したい](https://ja.stackoverflow.com/q/94578/14055)
3. 期間中に最も多くのプラス投票を得た回答の投稿者
   **齊藤敦志 さん**
   [image: 齊藤敦志]
   [xmlの名前空間をhttpsにしてはいけない？](https://ja.stackoverflow.com/a/94572/3364)

おめでとうございます！！！

Winner のみなさんへ：
のちほど、賞品の送付についてのメールをお送りいたします。

参加されたみなさんへ：
たくさんのプラス投票をありがとうございました。プラス票を投じてくださった方々はもちろん、受け取られた方々も、このキャンペーンを通じてみなさんの毎日に少しでもプラスの効果をもたらすことができていれば幸いです。